# iPhone has UITableView, what does android have

Tags: java, android, uitableview

I have an app on the iPhone that is completely table view driven. On android all I see is a static table, how can I create a table that I can populate with data that I requested from the network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use either `ListView` or `GridView`. `ListView` has a method `getView` which you override to  customize `ListView item`. This very much like `(UITableViewCell *)tableView...` in iphone, except that you needn't count the height of each cell. If you want to have something like tableView with sections you could use `ExpandableListView`. Here are links to [Android ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html), [Android Expandable ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) and [Android GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html). There can also be found very useful examples in Android Dev web-site.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GridView` or `ListView` with custom View for row. In both cases you can supply a `BaseAdaper` (or a subclass of it) through which you can manipulate the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the exact grid border like example here you go [Android Grid Border](http://hossaindoula.blogspot.com/2011/06/for-who-are-just-searching-for-gridview.html)... Obviously you can render data dynamically from whatever the source is...